# Are there any differences between "string" and 'string' in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am newbie in Ruby.

Are there some differences between "string" and 'string' in ruby?

such as

```
txt_data.gsub("ABC",'')
```

and

```
txt_data.gsub('ABC','')
```

It seems they are always the same.
Are there some cases where we need to use "" and '' selectively?

Comment: You couls also have written it for instance as `txt_data.gsub(%(ABC),'')`.  There are other ways to. Look here for an overview of [Ruby String literals](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is, you could interpolate the value when you use "" but you can't when you use ''

See the below example

```
value=23

a="The value is #{value}"

p a

a='The value is #{value}'

p a
```

Output

```
"The value is 23"
"The value is \#{value}"
```

Comment: There are other differences such as which backslash-escapes are supported.